# Overcross 30GB limitation quota W2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, quota

I want to configure quotas on `Windows 2008 R2` but when I try to set the value to 50GB (50000000ko) it throws an error which says that the maximum have been reached and the value is set to 30GB :

[image: Limitation warning image]

I try [this](http://malfroidt.com/blog/?p=461) solution :

```
<policy name="LimitSize" class="User" displayName="$(string.LimitSize)" explainText="$(string.LimitSize_Help)" presentation="$(presentation.LimitSize)" key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" valueName="EnableProfileQuota">
      <parentcategory ref="UserProfiles" />
      <supportedon ref="windows:SUPPORTED_Win2k" />
      <elements>
        <text id="SizeMessage" valueName="ProfileQuotaMessage" />
        <decimal id="ProfileSize" valueName="MaxProfileSize" required="true" minValue="300" maxValue="30000000" />
        <boolean id="IncludeRegInProQuota" valueName="IncludeRegInProQuota" />
        <boolean id="WarnUser" valueName="WarnUser" />
        <decimal id="WarnUserTimeout" valueName="WarnUserTimeout" required="true" />
      </elements>
</policy>
```

on the file `%SystemRoot%\Windows\PolicyDefinitions\UserProfiles.admx` but it's locked...

So, how can I overcross this ?

Comment: What do you mean "locked"? And... are you sure you want a 50GB storage quota for user profiles? Seems a little absurd

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen By locked I mean I need the authorization of `TrustedInstaller` to modify it and I can't change owner. I know this is *totally* absurd but I can't answer this to my teachers :/

Comment: Why don't you enter your quota in GB instead of KB?

Comment: @ETL because I can't choose GB nor MB

Answer (score 0):

If group policy is imposing a limit, the only way to change that limit is to edit the policy. It sounds like you are not an administrator on your computer or domain. Therefore, you will not be able to make this change on your own.

Comment: As I'm connected as a local admin and admin of the Active Directory, I don't know want to do more...